# Why my C# code is causing a Stack Overflow

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is the code giving a stack overflow it only happens about half the time and i have no idea why it's doing it. From what I seen it only happens with the Coms(TopCom, etc) are in a mass of numbers so around 5+ then it stack overflows.

```
public bool getConnected(int d) {
    if (topCom.connection != null) {
        if (d != topCom.connection.id) {
            if (topCom.connection.id == 0) {
                return true;
            } else if (topCom.connection.connected == true) {
                if (Development.instance.currentDos.buttons[topCom.connection.id].getConnected(id)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (leftCom.connection != null) {
        if (d != leftCom.connection.id) {
            if (leftCom.connection.id == 0) {
                return true;
            } else if (leftCom.connection.connected == true) {
                if (Development.instance.currentDos.buttons[leftCom.connection.id].getConnected(id)) {
                    return true;
                } 
            }
        }
    }

    if (rightCom.connection != null) {
        if (d != rightCom.connection.id) {
            if (rightCom.connection.id == 0) {
                return true;
            } else if (rightCom.connection.connected == true) {
                if (Development.instance.currentDos.buttons[rightCom.connection.id].getConnected(id)) {
                    return true;
                } 
            }
        }
    }

    if (botCom.connection != null) {
        if (d != botCom.connection.id) {
            if (botCom.connection.id == 0) {
                return true;
            } else if (botCom.connection.connected == true) {
                if (Development.instance.currentDos.buttons[botCom.connection.id].getConnected(id)) {
                    return true;
                } 
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: have you tried to debug your code? We don't even know the definition of your structure - all we know is that yes the code might end up in a infinite loop (when the current instance and one of the `topCom` form *a loop*) - I cannot possible give a sensible solution other than passing a `HashSet` with *already visited* nodes along so that you can detect loops

Comment: I been Using stack traces and Debug statements for the last four hours i just tried to clean up the code for showing.

Comment: Then you have to rethink your algorithmn (we know nothing about) - you **have to** find some way to break free of cycles in your graph - I told you one possibility (using a HashSet with the visited nodes)

Answer (score 1):

This happens in recursive functions where you don't have a base condition for ending the recursion. You basically keep calling the function until you reach stack overflow.. Trace your code through and figure out why it calls itself endlessly.

Comment: But should just go trough until it true or false and trace back up or at thats what my stack trace says half the time.

Comment: And if i'm understanding what you saying if do a return mid function it keeps going trough the function?

Answer (score 1):

The fact that people here can't really tell what you're trying to accomplish is a code smell of sorts.

A big part of that is the fact that you have an incredible amount of nesting in your code. Nested conditionals increase the difficulty of debugging code, as you're discovering now. Additionally, you could easily combine some of your conditionals - all of your conditionals in any top-level branch can actually be combined into one statement, as follows:

```
if ((topCom.connection != null  && d != topCom.connection.id && topCom.connection.id == 0) ||  
    (topCom.connection.connected == true &&  
     Development.instance.currentDos.buttons[topCom.connection.id].getConnected(id))) 
{
    return true;
}

return false;
```

As far as I can imagine, there's no point in having separate conditional branches that perform the same function, e.g. if (a) { return true; } else if (b) { return true; }. Just move the logic from else if into the original if conditional.

However, I'd recommend encapsulating some or all of this logic into a separate function, given that it seems like you're performing the same logic on each of your connections. You could create a function like so:

```
public bool ConnectionIsValid(connectionObject // replace with the actual type)
{
    if (topCom.connection != null  && d != topCom.connection.id && topCom.connection.id == 0)
        || (topCom.connection.connected == true 
        && Development.instance.currentDos.buttons[topCom.connection.id].getConnected(id))
        return true;

   return false;
}
```

So that you could then just call ConnectionIsValid on each of your connections, rather than using 80-some lines on conditionals for each connection.

It also seems doubtful that there's a StackOverflowException occurring in this code. Unless you have a circular reference related to any of the objects referenced in this code (in which case, there's a decent chance you used a setter accessor to assign a value to the same variable: 
    object A
    { 
        set 
        { 
            this.A = value; 
        } 
    }

which will always cause a stack overflow, it's likely you've introduced some sort of recursion outside the scope of the included code.

Comment: Yea but then it would give one big NullReferenceException all over the place. Wrote pre-edit

Comment: Nothing should give a NullReferenceException, unless I've made a mistake. One of the important aspects of the and (&&) operator is that it ceases operation if it encounters a single false statement within any specific scope, so the statement A != null && A != 12 will never throw NullReferenceException because A != 12 will never be checked should A be null.